# Как авторизироваться в SMTP mail.ru через JavaMail API?

Tags: java, smtp, javamail

Пытался написать простенькое учебное приложение для отправки писем по почте при помощи JavaMail API, в качестве SMTP сервера выбрал mail.ru. Но при попытке отправить сообщение выскакивает ошибка авторизации. Мне кажется я не так подключаюсь к сессии.
Код метода отправки письма:

```
public void sendMessage(String to) {
        final String from = this.mail;
        final String password = this.password;
        String host = "smtp.mail.ru";

        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator(){
                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPassAuth(){
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(from, password);
                    }
        });

        try {
            Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, InternetAddress.parse(to));
            message.setSubject("Test message");
            message.setText("This message sended by JavaMailApi");
            Transport.send(message);
            System.out.println("Success");
        }catch (MessagingException e){
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }

    }
```

String from - моя почта
String password - пароль от этой почты.
Выбрасывает такую ошибку: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException`

Comment: Вот здесь подробно описано https://stackoverflow.com/a/2033124/13483092

Answer (score 2):

Необходимо добавить следующее в property:

```
props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.checkserveridentity", true)
props.put("mail.smtps.ssl.trust", "*")
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true")
```